# Value of useState not set on initial render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am starting to use Hooks, and I have come to an issue.

I have this `priceToFilter` piece of state:

```
const [priceToFilter, setPriceToFilter] = useState(0)
```

Initially set to `0`, it renders `0` correctly, on the initial render.

But the thing is, I want its value to be the length of an array I am fetching on the inital render with a `useEffect` hook

But I dont know the length of that array, until the component mounted.

So, in this function, I am trying to acces priceToFilter, but it returns `0`, as that is its initial value.

```
  function filterResutls() {
    setFilteredResults(results.filter(x =>  {
      return x.stars <= stars && x.price <= priceToFilter
    }))
  }
```

But if you see in the `useEffect`, I am setting `priceToFilter` via the `setPriceToFilter` function to another value.
But, as the `useEffect` happens after the inital mount, it doesnt get the new value, but stays as `0`.

Any ideas on how to get that updated value for `priceToFilter` on the first render?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHotels(endpoint)
      .then( data => {
        setFilteredResults(data)
        setresults(data)
        const max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map((x) => x.price ))
        setMaxPrice(max)
        setPriceToFilter(max)
        filterResutls()
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('MAKE SOMETHING IN UI', e))
    }, [endpoint])
```

Comment: Makes sense, you are running `filterResults`  before `setPriceToFilter` is resolved. You should probably run it outside `useEffect` after the state is updated.

Comment: Keep a boolean in the state that serves as a flag (or use the data availability itself) to prevent filtering (or rendering) until the data is fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a second `useEffect` to listen to the price update and then filter the results accordingly:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function filterResutls() {
    setFilteredResults(results.filter(x =>  {
      return x.stars <= stars && x.price <= priceToFilter
    }))
  }

  filterResults();
}, [priceToFilter, stars])
```

The related functionality should be also removed from the first hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchHotels(endpoint)
      .then( data => {
        setresults(data)
        const max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map((x) => x.price ))
        setMaxPrice(max)
        setPriceToFilter(max)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('MAKE SOMETHING IN UI', e))
    }, [endpoint])
```

A more robust approach would be not to store filtered data on the state, but derive it during the render:

```
 return results
      .filter(x => x.stars <= stars && x.price <= priceToFilter)
      .map(result => <p>Price: {result.price}</p>);
```